# Stripping pasted contents of letters and symbols using JS / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code handling normal typing - it only allows numbers and not letters, symbols, or spaces:

```
self.press = function (data, event) {
        if (event.which == 0 || event.which == 32 || isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.which))) {
            event.preventDefault(); //stop character from entering input
        } else if (event.which == 13 && self.search().length != 10) {
            toastr.warning('number must be 10 characters');
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if (event.which == 13 && self.search().length == 10) {
            // nav to /k/#
            window.location.replace("/k/" + self.search());
        }
        return true;
    };
```

But I can paste letters and symbols into the field.  How can I strip any non-numbers from whatever's pasted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the input field's `oninput` event to listen for changes in content, and handle accordingly:

```js
$("#field").on('input', function(v){
    var val = $(this).val();
    val = val.replace(/\D/g, '');
    $(this).val(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="field" />
```

Note: The `oninput` event is only supported in IE 9 and up. To support older browsers, you can use `setInterval` to repeatedly check the inputs contents, or you can try [this shim](http://benalpert.com/2013/06/18/a-near-perfect-oninput-shim-for-ie-8-and-9.html).